# Dagger 2 - Constructor injection - Scope

Tags: java, android, dagger-2

I'm using Dagger 2 with simple MVP pattern. I have a `@PerApp` and `@PerActivity` scopes. I'm injecting presenters dependencies using constructor injection, which makes those presenters "injectable" (I don't need to write provides methods in activity module). Code fragments:

**PerApp:**

```
// AppComponent
@PerApp
@Component(modules = {AppModule.class, DataModule.class, NetworkModule.class})
public interface AppComponent {
    LoginComponent plus(LoginModule loginModule);

    MainComponent plus(MainModule mainModule);
}

// Example @PerApp module
@Module
public class NetworkModule {

    @Provides
    @PerApp
    Retrofit providesRetrofit(){
         ...
    }
}
```

**PerActivity:**

```
// LoginModule
@Module
public class LoginModule {
    private final LoginActivity mLoginActivity;

    public LoginModule(LoginActivity loginActivity) {
        mLoginActivity = loginActivity;
    }

    @Provides
    @PerActivity
    Context providesContext() {
        return mLoginActivity;
    }
}

// LoginComponent
@PerActivity
@Subcomponent(
        modules = LoginModule.class
)
public interface LoginComponent {
    void inject(LoginActivity loginActivity);
}
```

Activity:

```
public class LoginActivity {
    @Inject LoginPresenter mPresenter;
}
```

Presenter:

```
public class LoginPresenter {

    @Inject
    public LoginPresenter(Retrofit retrofit) {
        ...
    }
}
```

It's working great. My question is: What will be the scope of provided `LoginPresenter`? Is it gonna be the same as `LoginActivity`? Should I annotate the presenter's constructor with `@PerActivity` or something?

Answer (score 6):

I've ran some tests to check by myself how exactly scoping works with constructor injection and here are my results.

#### 1) Inject `LoginPresenter` into `LoginActivity`:

`LoginComponent` - `@PerActivity` scope *(code is exactly the same as in my first post)*.

I've tried to inject presenter into 2 variables:

```
public class LoginActivity {
    @Inject LoginPresenter A;
    @Inject LoginPresenter B;
}
```

`LoginPresenter` annotated with:

- ***nothing*** - `A` and `B` are different
- ***@PerActivity*** - `A` and `B` are the same
- ***@PerApp*** - `A` and `B` are the same

#### 2) Inject `LoginPresenter` into `LoginActivity` and `MainActivity`:

`LoginComponent`, `MainComponent` - `@PerActivity` scope *(code is exactly the same as in my first post)*.

I've tried to inject presenter into 2 different activities:

```
public class LoginActivity {
    @Inject LoginPresenter A;
}

public class MainActivity {
    @Inject LoginPresenter B;
}
```

`LoginPresenter` annotated with:

- ***nothing*** - `A` and `B` are different
- ***@PerActivity*** - `A` and `B` are different
- ***@PerApp*** - `A` and `B` are the same

Answer (score 3):

**It all depends on the component you're using for injection.**

Let's assume:

1. This is the component you're using for injecting stuff into your `LoginActivity`:

```
@PerActivity
@Component(dependencies = ApplicationComponent.class, modules = LoginActivityModule.class)
public interface LoginActivityComponent {
    void inject(LoginActivity loginActivity);
}
```

2. You use an `ApplicationComponent` for providing objects from `@PerApp` scope

---

If you don't specify the way a particular `module` should provide a particular object (`LoginPresenter` for example), you're basically saying to your `component`:

> I need a `LoginPresenter` instance. I don't care who creates that. Just figure that out yourself.

This component checks if any of the dependent `components`/`modules` knows how to create that. If not, the asked `component` needs to create that itself (with some help from the dependent dagger elements).

An injecting `component` can only try to reference ("create") objects that are from the same scope. So if the `LoginActivityComponent` is from `@PerActivity`, it can create object that are only from this scope.

If you don't specify the scope in your `LoginPresenter`, dagger will assume the same scope as the injecting component. If you specify explicitly `@PerActivity` scope, it will match the `component` scope and everything will be ok. But if you specify a different scope (e.g.`@PerApp`), your app won't build correctly since no class from the `@PerApp` is providing the way of creating `LoginPresenter`.

*Disclamer: There might be few parts of my explanation that I have been simplified, so it's a bit easier to understand (mostly in terms of who exactly does what). I tried not to make any simplifications that contradict the logic of the Dagger2 itself.*

Answer (score 3):

It seems the way to specify the scope when having a constructor with an `@Inject` annotation is to annotate the **class** with a scope:

```
@PerActivity
public class LoginPresenter {

    @Inject
    public LoginPresenter(Retrofit retrofit) {
        ...
    }
}
```

I assume `LoginPresenter` gets injected only in `LoginActivity`, which means *Dagger* will provide it only once and create a single instance of it. If you injected it multiple times, without the scope annotation you would get different instances.